# Certification logos on Careers site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I would like to make a feature request that would allow us to upload or link to a logo for a certification.

I love the idea of using Careers 2.0 to generate my resume, but I would really like to see my cert logos on there.

For example:

[image]

Would this be possible?  Thanks for considering!

Comment: Might I ask, why the downvote?  Is this not the right place to ask for this?

Comment: FYI, you are in the right place, but according to the [faq#vote-differences], voting on meta is different and sometimes indicates disagreement. Therefore, someone may just disagree with your request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the profiles are meant to fit your (the candidate's) standards, we also want to make sure that employers have an easy time reading them.  That's why even though we offer a lot more than a standard resume (SO answers, Open Source projects etc...) the layout is similar to a standard resume.

I worry that including these images, or other images/logos for companies you worked for, will turn some profiles into a NASCAR* monstrosity and turn off employers from otherwise good candidates.

*for those unfamiliar with NASCAR
[image]

Comment: Hah! You make a good point.  I guess my only argument would be that if someone does that, they're only hurting themselves.  But thanks for the consideration :)

Comment: +1 for using the GoDaddy car as the example.